# GEF EditPartViewer selection

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-gef

I'm experimenting a strange issue developing Drag and Drop with GEF.
If I start a drag operation of a not yet selected element in a org.eclipse.gef.ui.parts.TreeViewer the selected element got from EditPartViewer.getSelectedEditPart() is different from the one obtained via the SWT Tree control (Tree.getSelection()).

This appens only when I start the drag operation without selecting an element in the tree before starting the operation:
steps to reproduce:
- select an element in a treeviewe
- start dragging an **unselected** element of the tree

now the method Tree.getSelection() return the dragged TreeItem but the EditPartViewer.getSelectedEditPart() still returns the selected editpart, not the dragged one.

How can I correct this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the drag tracker of the editpart you select is only applying the viewer.setSelectedEditParts(eps) on mouseUp event, drag itself starts from mouseDown event. Not totally sure, should check how that default DragTracker works, or if you have overridden it, check that it is working correctly.